# How do I check if the data in column 6 of my Spreadsheet A exists in the column 1 of my Spreadsheet B?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to check if the  newly inserted values in column 6 match the records in another google sheet, and I want to reject the  user input if it does not match. What is the issue(s) of my code below?

```
function onnameEdit(e) {var range = e.range;var sheetName = range.getSheet().getName();var column = range.getColumn();var row = range.getRow();var inputValue = e.value;
```

```
if (sheetName == 'Join Queue [FOR ADVISEES]' && column == 6) {var sName = inputValue;var db = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1jdEUJK2uw71YAn_AeK3uEQK77oOtGCVOI12TJHWN0QE').getSheetByName('Login');var snameExists = false;
```

```
var recordsData = db.getRange("B:B").getValues(); // Assuming the names are in column B (column 2)
for (var i = 0; i < recordsData.length; i++) {
  if (recordsData[i][0].toString().toLowerCase() === sName.toString().toLowerCase()) {
    snameExists = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (!snameExists) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The entered name does not exist in the records. Please register first, or make sure you're entering the correct name.");
  range.clearContent();
} else {
  var dateCell = range.offset(0, 3); // Assuming the date will be written 3 columns to the right of the edited cell
  if (dateCell.getValue() === "") {
    dateCell.setValue(new Date()); // Set current date and time
  }
}
```

```
}}
```

Additionaly, I also want to ensure that a datecell will be added if the user input is accepted00

Comment: I think that your script works. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from your question. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. So, can I ask you about the details of your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I have two separate spreadsheets. Spreadsheet 1 acts as a database of my program, and it collects the name and email of users during registration process. Meanwhile, spreadsheet 2 handles most of the program processes. One of those process will require the user to input her name on a queue, but before he can successfully enter his name, I should first confirm that he already has a record in Spreadsheet 1. I would like to know how can I check for that. And I also want to achieve these results: 1) Accept user and automatically add date for entry, and 2) Reject and clear the cell he edited

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `but before he can successfully enter his name, I should first confirm that he already has a record in Spreadsheet 1.`, can I ask you about the details of `before he can successfully enter his name`? In this case, before the user puts the values, how do we know about it? For example, do you show the list of candidates as a dropdown list?

Comment: no, there will be no dropdown list. I might have phrased that part incorrectly, but to fully explain it, what will happen is that the  user will access the  spreadsheet 2 directly, where queuing slots awaits, and if he wants to enter that queue, he will have to enter his name on column 6. So in that case, I think I would like this function to run only when he finally entered the value in the said cell.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion:

Since the event object `onEdit()` won't work because `openById()` requires authorization, the workaround that I did here is to use installable trigger.
For your reference about the [restriction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions:%7E:text=They%20cannot%20access%20services%20that%20require%20authorization.%20For%20example%2C%20a%20simple%20trigger%20cannot%20send%20an%20email%20because%20the%20Gmail%20service%20requires%20authorization%2C%20but%20a%20simple%20trigger%20can%20translate%20a%20phrase%20with%20the%20Language%20service%2C%20which%20is%20anonymous.).

You can give this script a try:

```
function checkData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = ss.getSheetByName("Join Queue [FOR ADVISEES]"); // spreadsheet B
  var activeCell = sheetName.getActiveCell();
  var row = activeCell.getRow();
  var column = activeCell.getColumn();
  var values = sheetName.getRange(2, 6, ss.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  
  
  if (column == 6) {
    var sName = values[sheetName.getActiveCell().getRow() - 2][0];
    var db = SpreadsheetApp.openById("16j979b6I9aYH1C05Eh6hqb3lkWSRpvDcd123456").getSheetByName('Login') // change this to your own spreadsheet id for Spreadsheet A
    var sNameExists = false;
    var recordsData = db.getRange("B2:B" + db.getLastRow()).getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < recordsData.length; i++) {
      if (recordsData[i][0].toString().toLowerCase() == sName.toString().toLowerCase()) {
        sNameExists = true;
        var dateCell = sheetName.getRange(row, column + 3);
        if (dateCell.getValue() == "") {
          dateCell.setValue(new Date());
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!sNameExists) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("The entered name does not exist in the records. Please register first, or make sure you're entering the correct name.");
      activeCell.clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Trigger setup:**

[image]

---

The script above achieve the following:

1. Accept user and automatically add date for entry.
2. If the user doesn't exist in Spreadsheet A, it rejects and clear the edited cell.

**Result:**

To further explain, Test 1 exist in Spreadsheet A while Test 3 don't.

[image]

I hope this works for your and let me know if you have any questions.

### References:

- [Manage triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually)